# How do I use FBUi to Share dialog url on different domain?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a webpage at https://www.example.com/contest and I want to add some Facebook Share functionality to it.

1. I create a new Facebook App. In the App settings I first add a Website platform using `https://www.example.com` as the domain name. Then I add an App Domain as `www.example.com`
2. I also add the Facebook JS SDK to the page per the instructions.
3. I have some images on this webpage that I want to be Sharable. I want people to be able to click a custom Share button and get the Share popup along to share the url to the image.

The problem I'm facing is that my images are hosted on a different domain (Cloudinary.com). I use the following JavaScript to instantiate the Share popup:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/myaccount/some/path/to/image.jpg',
}, function(response){});
```

When I do this, I get an error in the Share popup:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

But in my App settings I can't add `res.cloudinary.com` to my "App Domains" because I get the following error:

> App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL
>   (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page
>   Tab URL. Please correct these domains: res.cloudinary.com

So what do I do here? Does Facebook only allow you to share items that are on the exact same domain as your Facebook App's domain? Considering how many people use subdomains, 3rd party solutions (imgix, Cloudinary, etc), etc. for hosting assets these days, that seems way too strict. Perhaps there is something I'm misunderstanding about this whole thing.

Why is it that anyone is able to use the simply Share Button configurator: (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) to make a Share button for ANY URL on ANY DOMAIN, but if you are trying to do something custom in a Facebook App then they limit you to your own domain?

Comment: You should rather not be sharing images directly in the first place, but proper HTML documents that contain relevant OG meta data, and have the image specified as the thumbnail.

Comment: Apps can deliberately limit what kind of URLs can be shared through them - that’s what the “Stream post URL security” setting (Settings -> Advanced) is for. But that has to be explicitly activated by the app admin.